# count the number of spaces in values in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need the number of spaces in column values in sql server.

Ex:

```
column1
------------
aaa bbbb   - 1 space
aaa bbb ccc - 2 space
aaa bbb ccc ddd - 3 space
```

I need the count of spaces like this.

thanks.

Comment: @mhasan there is a big difference from counting commas to spaces. If you test my answer you can see why.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
SELECT LEN(column1)-LEN(REPLACE(column1, ' ', '')) FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: Works but if you add "FROM TableName" part after the brackets.

Answer (score 12):

This will give a different and more accurate result than the other answers, it is also counting spaces in the end of the words, it becomes clear when tested on these examples:

```
DECLARE @a table(column1 varchar(20))
INSERT @a values('b c ')
INSERT @a values('b c')
INSERT @a values('   b c      ')

SELECT 
LEN(column1 + ';')-LEN(REPLACE(column1,' ','')) - 1 accurate,
LEN(column1)-LEN(REPLACE(column1,' ', '')) [inaccurate] -- other answers
FROM @a
```

Result:

```
accurate    inaccurate
2           1
1           1
10          4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (txt VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t (txt)
VALUES 
      ('aaa bbbb')
    , ('aaa bbb ccc')
    , ('aaa bbb ccc ddd')

SELECT txt, LEN(txt) - LEN(REPLACE(txt, ' ', ''))
FROM @t
```

Comment: @Devart your answer doesn't return the correct count when there are spaces in the end of the text. It will ignore the last spaces when counting.

Answer (score 2):

this is a code for that

```
select len('aaa bbb') - len(replace('aaa bbb ccc', ' ', '')) from 
**tablename**
```

output

1

```
select len('aaa bbb ccc') - len(replace('aaa bbb ccc', ' ', '')) from 
**tablename**
```

ouput

2

Tablename acan be anything table that can be in your database